# How can I implement custom attributes in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, custom-attributes

Unfortunately I am still working on .NET 2.0. I have not created a custom attribute before.
I want to create a `CustomStringFormatAttribute`:.

If a class, say Customer.Name, has:

```
MaxLength=30
ActualLength=10
```

I need to pad it with empty spaces till it reached 30.

I also need an attribute for date that I can format like DisplayDataFormat

I have created the following but **How do I get access to the actual value of the property within the attribute?**

```
public class Customer
{
    [CustomStringFormatAttribute(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //todo:customDateAttribute
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class CustomStringFormatAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly int maxLength;

    public CustomStringFormatAttribute(int maxLength)
    {
       MaxLength = maxLength;
    }

    public  int MaxLength { get; private set; }

    //?Should I override ToString 
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Format();
    }

    private string Format()
    {
        //simplified version of my formatting for brevity
        string source = "value from the property of the class.";//How do I get access to the actual value of the property within the attribute?
        const char paddingChar = ' ';
        return source.PadLeft(maxLength, paddingChar);
    }    
}
```

Any suggestions?

Note: I' used automatic property for brevity. I don't have that luxury in .NET 2.0.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're trying to accomplish but it is likely that you are using attributes inappropriately.  An attribute is associated with a type, not with an object of that type.  If you need a custom display format for a particular object then you *have* to use a plain property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot access the class instance or the property info inside your attribute.
You should write an additional method, for example a static method in some "static" class, that allow you to do what you want to do.

Example....

```
    public static string FormatProperty(object instance, PropertyInfo property)
    {
        CustomStringFormatAttribute attrib = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(CustomStringFormatAttribute)) as CustomStringFormatAttribute;
        return property.GetValue(instance, null).ToString().PadLeft(attrib.MaxLength, ' ');
    }

    public static string FormatProperty(object instance, string propertyName)
    {
        return FormatProperty(instance, instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance));
    }
```

But this is very uncomfortable and insanely slow since uses reflection to get property value through property info.

To access property attributes you need a PropertyInfo.

```
    public static int GetPropertyMaxLength(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        CustomStringFormatAttribute attrib = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(CustomStringFormatAttribute)) as CustomStringFormatAttribute;
        return attrib != null ? attrib.MaxLength : int.MaxValue;
    }

    public static int GetPropertyMaxLength(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        return GetPropertyMaxLength(type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance));
    }
```

Let's suppose we put these functions inside the attribute.
Then we want to override, for example, our ToString method in our class Customer.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return CustomStringFormatAttribute.FormatProperty(this, "Name");
}
```

The problem with this is of course Speed, it uses reflection by name, very slow, and Refactoring, you will not have a compile time warning or error if property "Name" doesn't exists, you will get only an exception at runtime. I would suggest you to use another mechanism.

With newer version of the language you could use lambda expressions to obtain your property info directly by the property itself, but since you are in C# 2.0 this is not possible.

Another solution can be: add instead another property called FormattedXXX, for example FormattedName that returns the lenght as you want it and you can use that property instead of the Name property.
This will allow you to keep your formatted version of the property near your property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.If my understanding is right of what you are saying that I dont gain anything by using attributes.   I wonder then how  MS achieves this then [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}")]

Comment: Instead of getting the value however probably you can reflection only to get the associated attribute and not the property value, but it depends on your application.

Comment: Thanks for your example.Need to write to a file 280 columns and each field has different formatting and is dictated by client specification.I thought rather than calling a function for each property I create something neater and use attributes on the property and code will be much cleaner.From what you saying I dont seem to have an option.

Comment: Well the problem is that you need to know at least the property name to access its attributes, so for your specific case can be quite uncomfortable, but it can work too. With other version of the framework you could use a lambda expression but with C# 2.0 things are quite complicated.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to use reflection how would I use your function within the attribute?In the ToStringOverride?

Comment: You have to specify the name of the property you want to get. Writing an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it the other way around. You shouldn't have any logic in your attribute, it should simply expose properties with the information it contains (e.g. a MaxLength property). Then your `Customer` class should access the information provided by `CustomStringFormatAttribute` and format it accordingly:

```
private string m_Name;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        var formatAttribute = typeof(Customer).GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                  .OfType<CustomStringFormatAttribute>
                                  .SingleOrDefault();

        if (formatAttribute != null)
            return m_Name.PadLeft(formatAttribute.MaxLength);

        return m_Name;
    }
    set
    {
        m_Name = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: GetCustomAttributes().OfType is slower than using Attribute.GetCustomAttribute, and he don't have linq since it is C# 2.0.

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti: It doesn't matter how to code looks exactly. It's the concept that attributes hold metadata accessed by other classes, and the attributes themselves don't actually do anything. Yes, you could micro-optimize (e.g. by saving the resulting attribute somewhere instead of accessing it via reflection each time), but it’s not my point. Also, using .NET 2.0 does not excuse you from using LINQ. Have you never heard of [LINQBridge](http://linqbridge.googlecode.com)?